# Is it possible to get current direction just like compass without internet in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, get, compass-geolocation, direction

I want to get direction in form of North-South-East-West [Example - 117' SE] in my iPhone application without using CLLocationManager and Internet.

Or How can i access Compass application to get Current degree values of direction.

Any help will be appreciated.

iPhone compass application works without internet so i think it should be possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is related to augmented reality. You can just refer the below link for details:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3997/introduction-to-augmented-reality-on-the-iphone

This may help you out...